# Styled-Select dropdown, positioning the option box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this styled-select dropdown, which shows only 5 options out of all existing options:

```
<div style="background:grey; height:400px; width: 400px;">
   <div class="styled-select">
      <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
          <option value="1">First</option>
          <option value="2">Second</option>
          <option value="3">Third</option>
          <option value="4">Fourth</option>
          <option value="5">Fifth</option>
          <option value="6">Sixth</option>
          <option value="7">Seventh</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how my css looks like:

```
    .styled-select select {
        position: absolute;
        background: transparent;
        width: 200px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        color: #4F9DD0;
        line-height: 1;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 4;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -o-appearance: none;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .styled-select {
        background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
        background-color: white;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .styled-select option {
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

I want it to act like this picture, I mean when I click on the main box in order to select one option, the window of options open starting from the below of main select box:

[image]

But this is what happens, which overlaps the main window:

[image]

Comment: @divix sure, but I prefer not to use any plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your script

```
onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;"
```

So you can remove it and just hide the extra options using css:

```
options:nth-child(n+6) {
   display:none;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.styled-select select {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #4F9DD0;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.styled-select {
  background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styled-select option {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

option:nth-child(n+6) {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey; height:400px; width: 400px;">
   <div class="styled-select">
      <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" >
          <option value="1">First</option>
          <option value="2">Second</option>
          <option value="3">Third</option>
          <option value="4">Fourth</option>
          <option value="5">Fifth</option>
          <option value="6">Sixth</option>
          <option value="7">Seventh</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Apparently, you can't hide an `option` tag using css on Mac OS, so in this case I suggest to use a plugin like [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/)

```js
$('select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity  
});
```

```css
select {
  width:100%;  
}

.select2-results__options li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:grey; height:400px; width: 400px;">
  <div class="styled-select">
    <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" >
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
      <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      <option value="5">Fifth</option>
      <option value="6">Sixth</option>
      <option value="7">Seventh</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Keep attention** about multiple `select`s in the same page. In this demo, all of the select's items with index greater than 5 will be invisible.

If you want to hide those options in specific select, you can add `class` to it and add the selector this class.

**Demo:**

```js
var con = $('select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
}).data('select2').$results.addClass("wrap");
```

```css
select {
  width:100%;  
}

.wrap.select2-results__options li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:grey; height:400px; width: 400px;">
  <div class="styled-select">
    <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" >
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
      <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      <option value="5">Fifth</option>
      <option value="6">Sixth</option>
      <option value="7">Seventh</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

Another solution (a little bit pache) that not required a plugin but use javascript (that's the requirement).

The idea is:

1. `button` to keep the selected value **and** will show/hide the `select` by click.
2. `select` with `size=5` which be hidden by default and toggle when user click on the button.
3. In the first click, the select will be displayed.
4. In the second click, the select will be hidden again **and** the selected value will by the text in the button.

**Demo:**
For unknown reason this snippet doesn't work right now, so you can see the effect in this [bin](http://jsbin.com/cijoqe/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('select').toggle();
});

$('select').change(function(){
  var sel = $(this).hide();
  $('#text-holder').html(sel.val());
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.wrapper {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

select {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}

button {
  text-align:left;
}

#text {
  border:1px solid;
  width:120px;
}

.arrow {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="text"> 
    <span id="text-holder"></span>
    <span class="arrow">▼</span>
  </button>
  <select size="5">
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know this.. Why do you remove those `option`s in the first place?

Comment: because I want to show only 5 options out of all existing options

Comment: So I can't see another choice but using a plugin.

Comment: So I will wait if somebody has a solution, by the way I will be thankful if you suggest the regarding plugin

Comment: but this one also does not show other options at all, it shows only 5 of them.
Really thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code and realized there is something not required for your expected output.

```
onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;"
```

The above shown statement can be removed and it works fine.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I want to show only 5 options out of all existing options, and that part which you quoted refers to this functionality